# Nodejs Sequelize Require Module with connection parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, sequelize.js

I have 2 database connections, one for read and one for write. I want to keep the read connection as default when a model is loaded.

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const readDB = require("../../config/readhost");
const writeDB = require("../../config/writehost");

const User = readDB.define(
"User",
  {
    email:...,id:...
    },
)
module.exports = User;
```

I want to use the model as usual for reading, but want to enforce write from certain controllers. Something like this

```
const User = require("../models/User"); --> Usual read
const User = require("../models/User")('write'); --> How to?
```

When passing the 'write', I want to use the writeDB instead of default readDB.
How to implement this change in Model or connection?
Maybe if I can pass the 'write' to the connection require of readDB and switch the host credentials there!

Tried this parameter passing. No error but can't access params.

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../config/database");

const Mod = db.define(
  "Mod",
  {..}
)
module.exports = (param='read')=>  Mod
```

I can require them with param. But how to access param at require of database in Mod?

```
const Mod = require("./Mod")();
const Mod2 = require("./Mod")('write');
```

How to pass param to either of these lines?

```
const db = require("../config/database");
const Mod = db.define(
```

Comment: Nevermind. I solved this using replication parameter in Sequelize. Tx. https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/read-replication/